# Regarding error on STS 4.6.1 64 bit version

Tags: java, spring-boot, sts

[image]

I am getting this error on STS 4.6.1 version which is 64 bit & Java 17 version is also 64 bit. Yesterday it was running properly. But when I run again it is showing error.

I checked both the STS & JDK & OS version. All are 64 bit only. But still facing this issue.

Comment: Check which jre/jdk is being picked by STS?
Window > Preferences > Installed JREs

Comment: Yes.. i pointed to JDK 17 only. But still facing the same issue.